# How many TB for Linux-only PyPI mirror?

Tags: python, pypi, mirror, bandersnatch

Roughly how many TB should be needed to hold a PyPI mirror for Linux only, using bandersnatch 3.6.0 installed with anaconda, and the default bandersnatch.conf plus:

```
[plugins]
enabled =
    exclude_platform

[blacklist]
platforms =
    windows
    macos
    freebsd
```

?

Spoiler alert: I'm up to 3.9 TB already (!) :)

Thank you very much.

-- Doug

P.S. I guess this comes down to: How much of PyPI is specific to Windows, macOS, and FreeBSD, as opposed to being general, or Linux-specific? https://pypi.org/stats/ says: "Sum of release files -- **ALL** of PyPI: 6.6 TB"

Comment: I don't believe there're FreeBSD packages at PyPI. There're source distributions and binary wheels for Linux, MacOS and w32. And only for AMD/Intel processors, no ARMs or MIPS etc. For ARMs there is https://www.piwheels.org/

Comment: As for the question — PyPI is most probably the only place where you can ask this question.

Comment: Where exactly do PyPI people discuss these kinds of things? I looked but couldn't find a likely place to ask the question. But I'd now go there and put a link to the answer, if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I was hoping that someone from the PyPI cognoscenti would answer with a search / query of some sort that would let me ask how many Linux and platform-general packages there are. Then I could just multiply by 3KB -- the average size of the first 10,000 wheels that were downloaded. But no such luck :(

Answer (score 3):

bandersnatch mirror download finally finished: 4,148 GB used.

(Took 230 hours, over a residential internet connection that Ookla https://www.speedtest.net/ reports as anywhere between 25 and 75 Mbps depending on time of day and how many Zoom sessions / youtube videos the residents are running.)